# How can I match {Tags} within visible html only and not within the elements attribute space?

Tags: php, html, regex, tags

Is it possible with just regexp (and or php) to get only a specific pattern which falls outside of a specific pattern and within a specific other pattern, in php (or possibly with ?R in php regexp for recursive aspect of it)?

The idea would be I want to match the tags that fall within > {ThisSpace} < and not within < {ThisSpace} > in a single line of visible html text.

An example of the single line of text is the following half html and tag mix combo

```
<div {IgnoreThis} id="{AndIgnoreThisOne}">I want to be able to only get {TheBracketTagsWithin} the visible html areas, excluding title and textarea and any html tag similar to those tags </div {AlsoIgnoreThese}>
```

I have tried making my own regexp for this, but failing.. I can use a combo of php & regexp, but missing something, or not understanding something here..

Here is what I am trying for regexp

```
(?<!\<\!--|\{|\<){([a-zA-Z0-9]*?)}(?!--\>|\}|\>)
```

This works to ignore the {AlsoIgnoreThese} in the end of the div, because of the next character being >, but I can not seem to modify this regexp in such a way that it will look forward until it finds.

I am coming around to realizing that this may be another thing needing a DOM parser, and I know... "You Cant Make An HTML DOM Parse With RegExp, Newb!"... I get that, so the question is how can I get a match or character position or anything for **only** the {Tags} that are within visible html? And without a DOM Parse telling me there are errors or not giving me any response because its broken HTML?

Any help is appreciated, even if it is just pointing me in the right direction.

Thanks!

**-EDIT-**

Something I forgot to mention, is since this is a single line of html, there may not always be the ending of the html tag (it may be on a future line), in the reverse there may not always be a start tag either and only an end tag. For lines which have no start or end tag, I already have a solution in place which accounts for "being within html space" or "being within attribute space", and so can safely be assumed that any line without an html start or end tag that has a {BracketTag} should be captured as well.

I feel like the answer is right at the tip of my fingers, but solving it is just a reach in the right direction..

Answer (score 0):

Why not use regex to search for each instance of >...<, then use your current code to search each match for tags?

EDIT: Try something like this: `(?<=>)(?:.*?)(?<={)(.*?(?=}))(?:.*?)(?:.*?)(?=})(?:.*?)(?=<)`

Look-behind for >, then non capturing group of everything up to {, capture everything up to }, non capture everything up to <. I think you want to give it a global modifier to get all possible results. You'll have to convert it to php

Comment: this feels more like a comment than an answer

Comment: Apologies, I shall see if I can move it

Comment: Oh, apparently I can't comment without 50 rep

Comment: @Elenchus, yea I've tried that, hence my regexp above. The issue being, if I have more than 1 tag in there, then the first > is captured and all characters even the next < seem to be captured until the next { even if that falls after another tag. I feel there has got to be a way to do it with the (?R) php recursive regexp tag & a few negative look-arounds, except I cant seem to get the right result. If you could provide more of an answer which solves finding a pattern within the > < scope, that may work for what I need it for.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't done regexp in a while. I got something working on regex101.com using non-capturing and capturing groups; answer edited with the code.

Comment: Actually, I just realised that'll only give you the first result even with the global modifier. But it should get you close

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '<div {IgnoreThis} id="{AndIgnoreThisOne}">I want to be able to only get {TheBracketTagsWithin} the visible html areas, excluding title and textarea and any html {tag} similar to those {tags} </div {AlsoIgnoreThese}>';
$str = preg_replace("/<.*?>/", "", $str);
preg_match_all("/{.*?}/", $str, $matches);
foreach ($matches[0] as $match) echo $match . "\n";
```